# Why ntpd prompt 'no server found' whenI sync time manually?

Tags: debian, ntp, ntpd

My server is hosted in IDC, due to in this IDC server can't access to Internet, so I can use Internet NTP server. But IDC service provider have a atomic clock, so I can sync time with atomic clock.
Atomic clock's IP is `192.168.90.118` and my server's IP is `192.168.90.18`. My server's OS is `Debian 8.11` and I install ntp by `sudo apt install ntp`, the version of ntpd is `4.2.6p5`.
Server's `/etc/ntp.conf` content like below:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
server 192.168.90.118 version 3
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

And I tried execute below command to sync time with atomic clock, it shows 'no server found'

```bsh
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpd -gq
```

I tried to ping the atomic clock's IP address, it is reachable and low latency.
I tried to capture some packets between atomic clock and my server with tcpdim,it shwos below:

```
sudo tcpdump -vvv -ni eth0 port 123

16:43:44.802334 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 126, id 12371, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), lenth 76)  
    192.168.90.118.123 > 192.168.90.18.123: [udp sum ok]NTPv3, lenth 48
        Server, Leap indicator: (0), Stratum 6 (secondary reference), poll 6 (64s), pricision -6
Root Delay: 0.000000, Root disprsion: 10.371246, Reference-ID: 95.31.153.26
            Reference Timestamp: 3843677595.431751999 (2021/10/20 08:13:15)
            Originator Timestamp: 3843708224.802159560 (2021/10/20 16:43:44)
            Receive Timestamp: 3843708322.196751999 (2021/10/20 16:45:22)
            Transmit Timestamp: 3843708322.196751999 (2021/10/20 16:45:22)
                Originator - Receive Timestamp: +97.394592739
                Originator - Transmit Timestamp: +97.394592739
16:43:46.802173 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 19514, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), lenth 76)  
    192.168.90.18.123 > 192.168.90.118.123: [bad udp cksum -> 0x4b29!]NTPv3, lenth 48
        Client, Leap indicator: clocl unsynchornized(192), Stratum 0 (unspecified), poll 6 (64s), pricision -23
Root Delay: 0.000000, Root disprsion: 0.000091, Reference-ID: (unspec)
            Reference Timestamp: 0.000000000
            Originator Timestamp: 3843708322.196751999 (2021/10/20 16:45:22)
            Receive Timestamp: 3843708224.1802334560 (2021/10/20 16:43:44)
            Transmit Timestamp: 3843708226.802159634 (2021/10/20 16:43:46)
                Originator - Receive Timestamp: -97.394417439
                Originator - Transmit Timestamp: -95.394592365
```

Above text are input manually.
Base on above result, it seem that `kernel` received the ntp packets, and protocol between server and client are match. But my server's ntpd didn't received or didn't recongized the packets. How can I fix it?

I executed command `ntpq -np`, it shows below:

```
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

Comment: Add the output of `ntpq -np` to your question.  Wait at least a minute after starting ntpd  and then run it.  Wait another minute and run it again, and put both outputs in your answer if they are different.

Comment: I executed `ntpq -np` it shows 'ntps: read: Connection refused'

Comment: Try it again prefaced by `sudo`.

Comment: Check which ntp server has the port `sudo lsof -i:ntp`. Read `man lsof`.

Comment: `ntpd -gq` makes just a one-time adjustment to the system clock and then quits. After that, you don't have a local `ntpd` running and so `ntpq -np` will fail until you do a `sudo service ntp start`.

Comment: Check for `iptables` firewall: it might be blocking UDP port 123. `tcpdump` uses raw sockets, so it will see incoming NTP traffic even if it would be blocked by `iptables`.

Comment: `ntpq -np` does not need sudo.

Comment: @telcoM Well, the reason I sync time manually by using `sudo ntp -gq` is ntp service can't adjust time automaticly so I want to locate the problem if ther is any wrong with networking or protocol compatible.

Comment: @waltinator I tried `sudo ntpq -np` it still display 'ntps: read: Connection refused'. And I tried `sudo lsof -i:ntp`, nothing display.

Comment: The service isn't running.  You need to start it with `systemctl start ntp` and if that fails, follow the instructions it gives to get the errors to find out why it didn't start.

Comment: @user10489 Okay I'll have a try.But  I think I can't sync time  manyually how ntp service can sync automiticlly?

Comment: Don't bother with `ntpq -np` now: it cannot work until you have run `service ntp start`. Instead, use `iptables -L -vn` to see if you have iptables firewall rules configured, and if you have, then read the list of rules to see if UDP port 123 is currently blocked. If it is, unblock it and then `sudo ntpd -gq` should start working without errors, and after that you should run `sudo service ntp start` and finally `ntpq -np` to check the NTP statistics.

Comment: When you start ntpd, watch your system log files (in /var/log) and look for ntpd diagnostic messages.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I has been found the reason why ntpd -gq not working.

Answer (score 1):

After ask my service provider, the NTP server is base on Windows, which protocol  is SNTP. In Debian 8.11's default NTP software, it can't accept SNTP packets. So  I need to upgrade ntp version.

Comment: If your upstream server is SNTP only, you need to find another upstream server.  Usually the default config file includes a handful of pool servers.

Comment: Well, for security reason, my server can't access to Internet. And in LAN, my data center service provider only have SNTP server, and refuse to provide ntp server. Not technical problem, but business problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state it in your question (but in comments) but you say that your system can't access internet, and can only access services in your data center, which do not include ntp but only sntp.

If a real ntp server is not available, and you can't get the alternative of GPS synchronization, then your only option is to disable ntpd on your system and use an sntp client, possibly in cron.

Comment: Errrrrr, I mentioned that my server can't access to Internet in the first sentence in my question. And after few days later after I post this this question, I finally confirmed from my service provider that the server's protocol is not NTP but SNTP.  And SNTP server seems working good with ntpd on CentOS and newer Debian version.

Comment: I didn't think it was clearly stated in the question, so I wanted to make sure the reasoning was clear in the answer.  If `ntpd -gq` is working well with their sntp server, then it is acting as an sntp client, and you will need to disable ntpd as a daemon and just run that command in cron periodically.